# Adding GUI in tkinter to a simpy simulation

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, simpy

I have a problem with implementing some GUI into my simpy simulation. The problem is how to add GUI, preferably made in Tkinter, to a simpy project. Wright now I have even problem with creating a window. I think that it's becouse when simulation stops running I can't exetue Tkinter code.. I know that this is a very general question, but I don't know how to start. What I want to do with Tkinter is to draw a topology for my simulation and maybe be able to make change some parameters, and run it from GUI.

I've added part when the simulation starts, and objects are created, the whole thing is more than ten times bigger so I don't know if i should add it here.

```
initialize()

network=Network()


#creating  nodes

node=Node(name='node', function='user', interfaceNum=2, possition=[160,990], homeAddress='0000000000000000020000fffe111111')
node.engine.stateTable={'wifiassocresp':'self.changeIp(interface, self.HO)','dissconnect':'node.engine.dissconnect(self.interruptCause, self.interruptCause.passSender)','RngRsp':'self.sendBU()', 'MIPv6BindingAck_LCoA':'self.sendBU(RCoA=True)', 'MihN2nHoCandidateQueryRsp':'self.makeHandover()'}
activate(node, node.start())

ap0=Node(name='ap0', function='ap', interfaceNum=2,possition=[200,1000])
ap0.engine.stateTable={'dissconnect':'self.dissconnect(self.interruptCause, self.interruptCause.passSender)'}
activate(ap0, ap0.start())

 ..... there is more nodes, but i cut it becouse I thinks that this is not important


activate(ha, ha.start())

ha.engine.HAadresses={'node':{ 
    'interfaceAddress':[node.interfaceList[0], node.interfaceList[0].address],
    'homeAddress':[node.homeAddress],}}


simulation=Tasks()


network.drawTopology(nodes=[node, ap1,ap2, map1, ap0, internet, ha])


allNodes=[node, internet, ap1, ap2, map1, ap0, ha]
node.apList=[ap0,ap1,ap2]

ap1.engine.createRouting([node, internet, map1, ap0, ap2, ha])
ap2.engine.createRouting([node, internet, map1, ap0, ap1, ha])
map1.engine.createRouting([node, ap1, internet, ap0,ap2, ha])
ap0.engine.createRouting([node, ap1, ap2, map1, internet, ha])
internet.engine.createRouting([node, ap1, map1, ap0,ap2, ha])


#here starts the simulation
activate(simulation, simulation.run(1))

simulate(until=100000.0)
```

And here is code for mu GUI

```
from Tkinter import *
from betaruch import *

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        ramka=Frame(master)
        ramka.pack()

        self.przycisk=Button(ramka, text="Wyjscie", fg="red", command=ramka.quit)
        self.przycisk.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.witam=Button(ramka, text="Uruchom", command=self.uruchomSymulacje)
        self.witam.pack(side=LEFT)        

    def uruchomSymulacje(self):
        pass

root=Tk()

onko=MainWindow(root)


root.mainloop()
```

And it's not suppoused to do anything, but it desn't even show up.

Ok maybe this will help. I've noticed that the problem occurs when I import both Tkinter and matplotlib. So maybe matplotlib is also using tkinter?

Comment: Hi Tobi, please consider adding your actual code and a concrete description of your problem (exception messages, screenshots, etc.). This information may be useful to help to solve this issue.

Comment: I don't have any errors, the problem is that window is not apperaing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are executing the code of your `betaruch` module in the same thread as your Tkinter code, so that is why your GUI is unresponsive. To solve this, you can execute the simulation in a new thread with the [`threading`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module:

```
import threading
from Tkinter import *
from betaruch import *

class MainWindow:
    # ...    

    def uruchomSymulacje(self):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=a_betaruch_function) # just a reference, without parentheses
        thread.start()
```

Comment: Thanks, but i've decided to solve it by simply dividing my simulator in two seperate programs: one for simulation, and one for making diagrams, plots etc. But I still have the same problem, but I've also noticed something:    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from Tkinter import *     when I delete importing matplotlib windows appear but with it they don't

Comment: OK that's werid but it seems that it was a problem with Wing IDE. Becouse the same code works if it's run in standard python IDE. Have anyone else had problem with importing Tkinter?